# WPF Style Inheritance with StyleTriggers / DataTriggers

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a few shape styles similar to the following:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}" x:Key="Triangle">        
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" />          
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,14L14,14 7,0 0,14z" />
 </Style>
```

Depending on some data values I may need the shapes to spin.  To do so I added the following Properties and Triggers to the Style:  (These work correctly)

```
 <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="5" CenterY="1" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger  Value="true" >
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <conv:IsSpinningConverter />
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="False" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="IsAcknowledged" IsAsync="False" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Spin">
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                            From="1" To=".0001" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Spin" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Adding this one Property and the Triggers to each shape feels cumbersome and inefficient.  So I had thought I could turn the RenderTransform Property and the DataTriggers into its own Property from which all shapes could be based like so:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}" x:Key="ShapeBase" >
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="5" CenterY="1" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger  Value="true" >
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <conv:IsSpinningConverter />
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="False" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="IsAcknowledged" IsAsync="False" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Spin">
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                            From="1" To=".0001" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Spin" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}" x:Key="Triangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ShapeBase}">        
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" />  
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,14L14,14 7,0 0,14z" />
 </Style>
```

When I do this however it seems the DataTriggers no longer fire as the shapes no longer spin.  Is there an issue using DataTriggers and Style Inheritance?  Is there something missing here that is keeping the DataTriggers from firing?

Thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue! Just found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757436/inherited-wpf-style-with-triggers-doesnt-work) workaround ...