# Inherited WPF Style with triggers doesn't work

Tags: wpf, triggers, wpf-style

I have a style that fades out a control with animation:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpireFadeStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!--Change this in a derived style if required-->
        <sys:Double x:Key="FinalVal">0.25</sys:Double>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpired}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ExpireAnimation">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="1" To="{StaticResource FinalVal}" Duration="0:0:3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ExpireAnimation" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(The `IsExpired` property always exists in the `DataContext` of the control where the style is supposed to be used.)

When I use this style directly in a control, it all works fine:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ExpireFadeStyle}">
    ...etc
```

But when I derive from this style, just as simple as

```
<Style x:Key="ExpireTextFadeStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ExpireFadeStyle}"/>
```

...and then use the derived style on the same control the same way, it doesn't work. (The intention is, of course, to change it a bit, particularly the `FinalVal`, but it has to work in a trivial case first).

The inherited style itself does seem to work: if I add some `Setter` to it, I see its effect. It just seems that `Triggers` are not inherited or simply don't work. How to work around it?

Answer (score 5):

That's really a good question. I created an example test application to check this out and I have faced exactly the same problem. In debug mode I checked the value of the Style property and it was correct (BasedOn was set correctly and BasedOn.Triggers contains your Trigger). Nevertheless, the Trigger doesn't fire up when needed.

I have found a solution that make this work, however it is not a perfect one...
I defined an attached dependency property which copies the triggers when is set to true.

```
public class StyleTriggersInheritanceHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddInheritedTriggersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AddInheritedTriggers", typeof(bool), typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAddInheritedTriggers)));

    private static void OnAddInheritedTriggers(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var b = e.NewValue as bool?;
        if (b.HasValue && b.Value)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if(element != null)
            {
                Style style = element.Style;
                if(style != null)
                {
                    Style baseStyle = element.Style.BasedOn;
                    Style newStyle = new Style() { BasedOn = style };
                    if(baseStyle != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var tr in style.Triggers)
                            newStyle.Triggers.Add(tr);
                        foreach (var tr in baseStyle.Triggers)
                            newStyle.Triggers.Add(tr);
                    }
                    element.Style = newStyle;
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    public static bool GetAddInheritedTriggers(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AddInheritedTriggersProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAddInheritedTriggers(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AddInheritedTriggersProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And xaml looks as follows:

```
<local:ExpirdedControl IsExpired="{Binding IsExpired}" Style="{StaticResource InheritedStyle}" x:Name="ExpiredName" local:StyleTriggersInheritanceHelper.AddInheritedTriggers="True"/>
```

Note that AddInheritedTriggers attached property is set to true and then Triggers are copied. One important thing is that you have to set AddInheritedTriggers after applying the Style, otherwise it wouldn't work!

For me it works, however the solution is not elegant, so I would like to see a better try of solving this issue.

Comment: Thanks! This proves the point, but indeed such a solution is hardly more elegant than simply copy-pasting the whole style with the necessary changes... I still wonder if it's a bug in WPF or 'feature', and what would be the 'right' way of inheriting the triggers...

Comment: I also just copied. Clearly, the styles are not inherited like OO inheritance.  Probably this is badly documented and/or not fully understood in the community.